# tensorflow library does not contain session attribute ,how to solve this problem

Tags: tensorflow

i am new to tensorflow and use it on jupyter notebook,the code block on execution show module tensorflow has no attribute session and tf.global_variables_initializer() is not working...help

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
x=tf.Variable(7)
y=tf.constant(5)
with tf.session() as sess:
    sess.run(global_variable_initializer())
```

Comment: reformat your code and also paste some errorcode. That might help out others to solve your problem. Did you check other questions related? If so, add that and what you tried to the question by editing it. That shows effort and removes your question out of the "triage" list. End of review.

Answer (score 0):

The s on session should be upper case:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

also the command is:

```
tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

wtih an s. Revise code to:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```